# Pic failing to upload camera pictures but uploading screenshots and saved pictures

Tags: php, ios, upload, camera, pic

I have a script that currently uploads saved pictures from the internet or screenshots. However, any pictures taken with the iPhone camera, it fails to upload. Why would that be? Is it a memory issue?

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './upload/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
{
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
    echo "yes";
}
}
else
{
echo $_FILES['userfile']['error']; //just returns "1"

}
?>
```

Here is the iOS:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaujez = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *rambli = [defaujez objectForKey:@"getpicforfu"];      


    NSData *imageData =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 90);
    NSString *imgPath= @"http://www.mywebsite.com/script.php";

        NSString *filenames = rambli;
        NSLog(@"%@", filenames);
        NSString *urlString = imgPath;

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filenames\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[filenames dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", rambli] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

       // [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
        // now lets make the connection to the web
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if([returnString isEqualToString:@"yes"])
        {
             [self finitop];

        }
        else {
            [spinner stopAnimating];
            rambolrqa.text = @"Posted Empty Because Upload Failed";

        }
```

Comment: You never bother checking if the upload succeeded. There's a `['error']` parameter in `$_FILES` for a reason: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: The upload did not succeed. I went to the server location and checked. It was not there.

Comment: so check the `['error']` to find out WHY it failed.

Comment: I keep getting the return value as a problem with unexpected [. That is most likely with the ['error']. Any other way I can get the return value?

Comment: I changed the error symptom to echo $_FILES['userfile']['error'];, which just returned 1.

Comment: so go look at the doc I linked to. it tells you what the codes mean.

Comment: Ok. So it exceeds the maximum. Is there anyway I can make just that file bigger maximum?

Comment: sure: read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: So, I am getting a 1 in the error, but my $_FILES['userfile']['error']; returns a 0. Only for camera pictures though.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it by compressing it on iOS to a reasonable size.

```
NSData *imageDataf = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((imageView.image), 0.5)];
int imageSize = imageDataf.length;

if (imageSize >50000) {
    //35414 normal
    //952683 camera
    if (imageSize >2000000) {
NSData *imgData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image,0.00001);
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
imageView.image = image;
    }
    else {
        NSData *imgData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image,0.001);
        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        imageView.image = image;
    }
}
```